# Difference between Ubuntu Base, Core, Minimal

Tags: ubuntu-core, versions, ubuntu-minimal

Is there a simple explanation of the differences or use cases of the three versions mentioned?

I need a secure digital system whith python support, internet access which only shows a browser. It should run on a Raspberry Pi. There is no commercial interest.

Comment: I would suggest a google search of each would be your best bet. There is just too much to be addressed here.

Comment: Ubuntu Core is not a *deb* based system thus the *yy* format of releases (unlike *deb* based system that are all *yy.mm* in format), have 10 years of support (longer than LTS + ESM in most cases) etc... Minimal is a full install with packages removed after the installed image is written to the disk.. The Ubuntu base is the same for all systems on which are all based (desktop, server, core etc)  The best for you depends completely on your intended use, applications etc.. which is a very opinion geared question which is off-topic here.

Comment: You provide no release details; the minimal ISO is also called Netboot which is a tiny boot installation media that downloads & installs from the internet... The minimal install I mentioned in prior comment refers to the desktop minimal-install option...  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Minimal  but you can search yourself

Comment: This is a good question, @guiverc, turn your comment into an answer an I will upvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu's main releases use *deb* package (*deb* are also used by Debian).  All *deb* based releases are *year.month* in format, eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop.

**Ubuntu Core** is not a *deb* based system thus uses a different format, namely *year* only, eg. Ubuntu Core 20. These releases can use *snap* packages only, no LTS gets mentioned normally as all releases have 10 years of support.

**Minimal** can mean two things, there is a minimal install option where the full install occurs (ie. installed image is written to the disk) then if you selected a minimal install, packages listed on a list are removed (creating the minimal install option).

There is also a **netboot** or ***mini*** ISO that is a network loader; it boots the system and asks what type of install & downloads all packages from the web & installs. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Minimal You may have meant that, but a minimal-install option is generally more common and what you mean.

The **Ubuntu base** is the same base found on all systems (be they desktop, server, core etc). See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base for more details.

There for sure are many other things to consider

- resources; what apps you'll use will dictate the most efficient system
- intended use
- support life versus latest software?
- how much maintenance are you willing to do, when etc..
  etc, each with pros & cons.

The best for you depends completely on your intended use, applications etc.. which is a very opinion geared question not encouraged here (better for forums, Ubuntu forums can be found at https://ubuntuforums.org/.

Comment: Nice answer +1. I wonder if adding a line for Ubuntu server would be worthwhile? I guess that was not part of the question though.

Comment: Here you state Ubuntu Core has 10 year support, is that EoSS or EoL? Please see this Meta post: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19720/whats-the-support-period-for-ubuntu-core?noredirect=1#comment42937_19720 Regards

Comment: I tend to use the language used in official notices I post to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/ (*& it's affiliated sites/mirrors*). Most of what is published to the fridge is actually cut/pasted from Canonical ML threads, though for UWN etc it's summaries that often I actually wrote (*thus it's my actual wording I'm quoting which is often why I remember it*). As everything published there is reviewed prior to release (*following rules, why release notices like 20.04.3 are delayed so long*) I have no issues with anything I quote from there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you say that the targeted platform is **Raspberry Pi**, then you'll need a dedicated image for this platform
(I mean : an image that will be compatible with the raspberryPi hardware such as processor, motherboard, integrated components).

Some ready-to-install images builds are available on RaspberryPi's official website
https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/

On the downloads page, there are the main official flavors of "Raspberry Pi OS":

- Raspberry Pi OS with desktop and recommended software
- Raspberry Pi OS with desktop
- Raspberry Pi OS Lite

Still on this page, there are also some [Ubuntu images](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/#third-party-software) built for RaspberryPi (but their names do not match exactly with what you've asked for :Ubuntu Base, Core, Minimal) :

- Ubuntu Desktop
- Ubuntu Server
- Ubuntu Core

(there are full descriptions near the downloads buttons of that page)

The UBUNTU's website provides some other builds here : https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi .

- Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 **LTS** => the LTS branch is the most stable (and advisable IMHO) if you do not need a GUI
- Ubuntu Server 20.10 ==> most recent, no GUI
- Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 ==> most recent, with GUI, heavy
  (you'll find a full explanation at the bottom of the page : "Which image should I pick?" On top of the page there are 2 links for installation tutorials, and some others tips called "Installation instructions" are provided on a page opened just after you pick a download)

More downloads here : https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/

( Focal builds for Raspberry, LTS versions available :  https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/focal/release/ )

I hope that you'll find what you wish !