# What is difference between ubuntu 18 and 20?

Tags: lubuntu, system, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-headers, blog

I hope to know what is difference between  ubuntu 18 and 20.
If you can help me, please post your answer.
Thanks.

Comment: You tagged this with *windows-subsystem-for-linux*, but your question just seems more to be about Ubuntu itself.  Did you want to know the difference between the three Ubuntu versions available in the Microsoft Store for WSL?  Or was that tag just accidental?  *blog* and *linux-headers* also don't seem to apply here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Ubuntu Base, Core, Minimal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332852/difference-between-ubuntu-base-core-minimal)

Comment: yeah, do you have another problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu has different products.

**Snap only products - *year* (18)**

The Ubuntu products using the *year* format are *snap* only, eg Ubuntu Core 18 is the 2018 release of Ubuntu Core for devices, appliances, but can also be used in cloud environments.  Ubuntu Core 20 is the 2020 release of the Ubuntu Core product.  All these products come with 10 years of supported life, so LTS is not used.

**Main *deb* products - *year.month* (18.04)**

The Ubuntu products using the *year.month* format are the main *deb* based releases, showing the year & month of release, eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is the 2020-April release of Ubuntu; the 20.04 format tells you it's *deb* package based and the LTS shows you it's a *long-term-support* release with 5 years of support (3 for flavors like Lubuntu).  Non-LTS releases have 9 months of supported life, and LTS products can have the life extended via the use of [ESM](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm).  These products can also use *snap* packages.

Lubuntu is a desktop, and does not have *year* or *snap* only releases, so Lubuntu 20.04 LTS has the LXQt desktop, is built on the Ubuntu 20.04 platform. It's apps & desktop differs to the Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop system (LXQt & Qt5 apps replaced the GNOME & GTK3 apps found on Ubuntu Desktop).

Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (or the 2018-April release) has [completed it's 3 years of supported life](https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/), but it used the older & *deprecated* LXDE environment, built on the (*deprecated*) GTK2 toolkit. It was the last Lubuntu release that used the LXDE desktop.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop using the GNOME desktop however has five years of supported life, so it still receives upgrades & security fixes.

Comment: FYI:  It's common to see home users, consumers & bloggers who don't work in IT to often refer to *deb* based releases using the *year* format as they don't care about precision. As they don't work in cloud/IT they rarely come across the device/appliance/cloud systems that can use the *year* products so don't keep up with products they don't use.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your post.

Comment: I use Lubuntu as example because you tagged it, but you can explore what's included online in many ways; you'll find a *manifest* file always where you download an ISO, it contains a list of the packages enclosed on that ISO. Beyond that packages.ubuntu.com provides a list of what's included, eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-desktop could be compared with the ubuntu-desktop (default Ubuntu desktop) to see differences between Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS & Lubuntu 20.04 LTS too, or compare the *focal* (20.04) with *bionic* (18.04) to compare releases; packages is how they're built