# What's the difference between `base` vs `server` image

Tags: server, 22.04

I would like to install NextCloud with snaps on a Libre Computer Board AML-S905X-CC 2GB per:

https://snapcraft.io/install/nextcloud/raspbian

Libre Computer publishes 3 ubuntu versions available at: https://distro.libre.computer/ci/ubuntu/22.04/

1. [base](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base)
2. desktop
3. server

I did find: [Difference between Ubuntu Base, Core, Minimal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332852/difference-between-ubuntu-base-core-minimal), however I am not sure what is meant by the `base` image.

I believe that I do not want the desktop version because it has a lot of nice, but unnecessary items installed. This leaves base and server.

I believe that base has less installed than server (judging from the image sizes). Can anyone clarify exactly what the difference might be between those images, and what might best fit my usecase (installing NextCloud as a snap)?

Comment: @user535733 Thank you for responding.  The Libre board manufacturer has compiled Ubuntu for their hardware.   Why would this not be a 'real' Ubuntu image?  Can I use any of the downloads from an Ubuntu download page on said hardware SBC?

Comment: Since we don't know what Libre put into those images (especially whatever they are calling "base"), such questions are answerable only by the Libre folks. Were I in your shoes, I would try several and see what works best. Then you can write the definitive, tested answer.

Comment: Did you look up any documentation; eg. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base covers Ubuntu Base

Comment: @ArturMeinild  What's the alternative?  Provide a link to the *seed* files for each, it's how I'd contrast a Server vs Desktop install...  with some description*.  Note: *I'm less familiar with the base as an installable entity though, but as packages that get included on all Ubuntu products given my involvement with a desktop flavor*

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Your Libre Computer references are re-spins of Ubuntu products, not Ubuntu products*

Comment: Raspbian is not Ubuntu.  And the Libre editions of Ubuntu/Debian/etc are *not* Official images

Answer (score 2):

*This is a qualified guess, since the Libre Computer editions of Ubuntu are not "official" images, and they don't provide any solid information on those (like a manifest file).*

- The Preinstalled Desktop image most likely has the [`ubuntu-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-desktop) metapackage installed.
- The Preinstalled Server image most likely has the [`ubuntu-server`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-server) metapackage installed.
- The Preinstalled Base image most likely has none of those metapackages installed.

But only you (as the OP and owner of the hardware) can test this to actually see if it's true.

How you choose between `base` and `server` is up to you. Since your particular usecase seems to be installing a predetermined Snap application, I'm think you can safely choose the `base` image, since you can always install any additional server packages afterwards if you should need them.

Comment: I hadn't noted the off-topic ISO references & thus *likley* off-topic nature of the question.  I'd contrast the *seed* files that the launchpad builders use to create the ISOs if I was contrasting the ISOs, alas that only applies to Ubuntu ISOs & not 3rd party as you noted the question relates to.